# Get value of glVertex3f and search the closest one

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm programming in openGL and i have a problem.

Im read a external file, this file contain a list of vertices.

Vertices: v# (x) (y) (z)

- v1 **(1.125) (2.63236) (0)**
- v2 **(1.12618) (2.62949) (0.720263)**
- v3 **(1.13523) (2.60264) (0)**
- v4 **(1.12496) (2.63244) (0)**

after open this file, my program take this vertices and draw points with glVertex3f(x, y, z);

And i have another function, when click in the window y get the coordinate, with this functions:

```
glReadPixels(x, height() - 1 - y, 1, 1,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &z);
gluUnProject(x + 0.5, viewport[3] - 0.5 - y, z, modelView, projection, viewport, &wx,&wy,&wz);
```

this, return a position of the mouse in the window, for example: (0.12618) (1.425549) (0.637102)

My question is, it's possible through the returned value when clicked in the window, search the point similar or more close in the file and use they?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between 2 points?

Comment: I need to compare if the value returned when clicking on the windows exists in the file or if there is one that comes closest

Comment: So you have to calculate the distance between the "click" point and each point of the file  and to search the shortest distance.

Comment: I got it. When click, compare the value return with each point in the file and search the shortest distance, so then, that would be the closest point in the file?